# Arduino BT (bluetooth) Boot Loader

Tags: arduino, bluetooth

How do you burn the Arduino Boot Loader onto the Arduino BT?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an AVR ISP programmer. You just plug it onto the 6-pin header on the arduino board and program it with the Arduino application.